# Operator Norm of T:$(C^1[0,1],||-||)\rightarrow (C[0,1],||-||_{\infty})$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

[image]
where,

[image]

I know that $||T||\leq 1$ but I cant seem to show the it is larger than 1. I can't seem to come up with any functions that would show that $||T||\geq 1$.

Any ideas?

Secondly, I'm assuming that inverse of T does not exist since it is not injective as $L(f)=L(f+c)$ where c is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given norm, the operator is continuous with norm at most 1. Indeed,
$$
||Tf||_\infty=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f'(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in [0,1]}(|f(x)|+|f'(x)|)=||f||
$$
As you say, the operator cannot be invertible as constants are in the kernel, and so it is not injective.

To compute the norm, take $f_n(x)=x^n$. Then, 
$$
||x^n||=1+n
$$
since 
$$
\sup_{x\in [0,1]}(|x^n|+|nx^{n-1}|)\leq 
||x^n||_\infty+||nx^{n-1}||_\infty=1+n
$$
but 
$$
\sup_{x\in [0,1]}(|x^n|+|nx^{n-1}|)\geq 1^n+n1^{n-1}
$$
and 
$$
||nx^{n-1}||_\infty=n
$$
so 
$$
\frac{||Tf_n||_\infty}{||f_n||}\to 1
$$

Comment: Any idea what the norm is? Is it 1?

Comment: By the way the ||f|| is not the sum of the individual norms. but sup(|f|+|f'|)